# LAME: Switch sample rate of file without reencoding?

Tags: audio, mp3, lame

Is it possible to resample an MP3 file to a different rate (44.1) without doing a reencode? I have a few MP3 files that are at 48 and I need to switch 'em to 44.1, and I don't want to have to reencode my files to do so, as I'll lose quality. The source files are at CBR 320 and at 48kHz. Can this be done?

The current way I'm doing it is using the following command:

```
lame -b 320 -q 0 --resample 44.1 input.mp3 output.mp3
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Yeah probably not. I'm not too familiar with the way that sample rate works in audio, but I'd assume that I'd have to reencode to change the sample rate. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit for it :) In the end, I just ended up doing the above and using `id3cp` to copy the ID3 tags over.

Comment: @Randolph you said it first...i just said it definitively...if you move your comment to an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: I have answered with a link to the Wikipedia article too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe this is possible. The sample rate is to do with the number of samples per second, which would require a re-encoding of the track to change this value.

See more on the Wikipedia article on [Sampling rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate).